# How to make bootstrap carousel indicators on navbar

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

My carousel is working fine, and slides perfect between each other, but i need to highligt the item as active class then slided to and clicking on the navbar li a. Can anyone help me in the right direction here?

HTML CODE:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
            </div>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"><a href="#">slide 1</a></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1"><a href="#">slide 2</a></li>
                    <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2"><a href="#">slide 3</a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </nav>    

<div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
       <div class="carousel-inner">
          <div class="item active">
             <div class="wrapper">
                <%-- Slide 1 --%>
             </div>
          </div>
          <div class="item">
             <div class="wrapper">
                <%-- Slide 2 --%>
             </div>
          </div>
          div class="item">
             <div class="wrapper">
                <%-- Slide 3 --%>
             </div>
          </div>
       </div>

       <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
          <span class="icon-prev"></span>
       </a>
       <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
          <span class="icon-next"></span>
       </a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 2):

I did it by breaking down the task in two stages. Removing the .active class from the old indicator and adding class .active to the new indicator.

I used Bosc's idea, but added an additional function within the first one.

Here is the example: http://www.bootply.com/NTPzTEm6dn

And here is the jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".carousel").carousel({
    interval: 5000
  });
  $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function() {


    $(".myCarousel-target.active").removeClass("active");

    $('#myCarousel').on('slid.bs.carousel', function() {

      var to_slide = $(".carousel-item.active").attr("data-slide-no");

      $(".nav-indicators li[data-slide-to=" + to_slide + "]").addClass("active");

    });
  });

});
```

```css
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover,
.navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
  color: #555;
  background-color: purple;
}
```

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-BVYiiSIFeK1dGmJRAkycuHAHRg32OmUcww7on3RYdg4Va+PmSTsz/K68vbdEjh4u" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</head>

<body>


  <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
      </button>
    </div>

    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
      <ol class="nav navbar-nav nav-indicators">
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="0" class="myCarousel-target active"><a href="#">slide 1</a>
        </li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="1" class="myCarousel-target"><a href="#">slide 2</a>
        </li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="2" class="myCarousel-target"><a href="#">slide 3</a>
        </li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="3" class="myCarousel-target"><a href="#">slide 4</a>
        </li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="4" class="myCarousel-target"><a href="#">slide 5</a>
        </li>
        <li data-target="#myCarousel" data-slide-to="5" class="myCarousel-target"><a href="#">slide 6</a>
        </li>
      </ol>
    </div>
  </nav>

  <div id="myCarousel" class="carousel slide">
    <div class="carousel-inner">
      <div data-slide-no="0" class="item carousel-item active">
        <div class="wrapper">
          &lt;%-- Slide 1 --%&gt;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-slide-no="1" class="item carousel-item">
        <div class="wrapper">
          &lt;%-- Slide 2 --%&gt;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-slide-no="2" class="item carousel-item">
        <div class="wrapper">
          &lt;%-- Slide 3 --%&gt;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-slide-no="3" class="item carousel-item">
        <div class="wrapper">
          &lt;%-- Slide 4 --%&gt;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-slide-no="4" class="item carousel-item">
        <div class="wrapper">
          &lt;%-- Slide 5 --%&gt;
        </div>
      </div>
      <div data-slide-no="5" class="item carousel-item">
        <div class="wrapper">
          &lt;%-- Slide 6 --%&gt;
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>

    <a class="carousel-control left" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="prev">
      <span class="icon-prev"></span>
    </a>
    <a class="carousel-control right" href="#myCarousel" data-slide="next">
      <span class="icon-next"></span>
    </a>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: it helped me with my solution

Answer (score 0):

Add some jquery/js that will add and remove the active class on click

```
$('.nav li').on('click', function(){
    $('li.active').removeClass('active');
    $(this).addClass('active');
});
```

update: http://www.bootply.com/nxah8CQozF dont have time atm to fix this up, it has a few errors like the first slide not becoming active again but hopefully you can figure it out or it at least gives you a starting point.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".carousel").carousel({
    interval: 5000
  });
  $('#myCarousel').on('slide.bs.carousel', function () {
    var to_slide;
    to_slide = $(".carousel-item.active").attr("data-slide-no");
    $(".myCarousel-target.active").removeClass("active");
    $(".nav-indicators [data-slide-to=" + to_slide + "]").addClass("active");
  });
});
```

Comment: http://www.bootply.com/nxah8CQozF or do you mean you need the next and prev arrows to also change the active class?

Comment: yes, when the user click on the prev and next arrows. its fine working now when click on the menu tabs/li

Comment: updated the bootply with something thats close to what you need, dont have the time though to fix it up, hope it helps.